# Im having an Error in one the the Page...says NullInjectoErro,,,No Post Provider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating my own database then the error shows that Null Injector Error No Post Provider

Answer (score 0):

`NullInjectorError` means you have to import the installed package through `app.module.ts` instead of directly importing it to your pages.